# How do I separate enchants from items?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there anyway I can separate enchants from items so I can put the enchants in a enchanting book?

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, you can't. You can remove enchantments from items in 1.14 by using the grindstone, but you won't be able to put it in a book: it will just de-enchant the item and you will get some experience.

Comment: On second thought I am sure you could do it with a datapack, using a custom dropper crafting setup.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't currently possible in vanilla Minecraft. However, there do exist mods that will let you do this (which will require Forge). One such mod is [The Disenchanter Mod](https://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/the-disenchanter-mod).

Comment: Hi Joseph, welcome to Arqade! Thank you for your positive and concise answer.